# How to hide ssh:// and port in URL

Tags: git, ssh

currently i use Gitblit as a repo manager, which is deployed as WAR behind apache tomcat (centOS 6.7).

To connect to repository I use URL (current state):

`git <command> ssh://<user>@<host>:29418/<repo>`

The expected way is (the "wanted" state):

`git <command> <user>@<host>:<repo>`

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <host>
    ErrorLog logs/gitblit_error_log

    ProxyRequests     off
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLog logs/apache-mod_rewrite
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gitblit-1.7.1.*
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /gitblit-1.7.1/$1 [L,PT]

    JkMount /gitblit-1.7.1* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I achieve that and still keep the ability to connect using SSH key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a config file for Apache, which is a web server.  It is the wrong configuration file.  Instead, change the client configuration for SSH.  This is located in `~/.ssh/conf` on your client (not your server).  Be sure to get the permissions correct or SSH will refuse to read it.

Here is a segment from my SSH config.

```
Host myserver
HostName example.com
Port 22000
User john
```

This way, when I do `git remote add`, I can do this:

```
git clone myserver:swordfish.git
```

Instead of this:

```
git clone ssh://john@example.com:22000/swordfish.git
```

You can even specify a different identity key per host, if you like.

Comment: What is the correct permission settings for .ssh/config? 

I have the following:
Access rights: `-rw-r--r--`
Content:
`Host *
Port 29418`

But still it doesnt work..

Comment: The `.ssh` folder must be 700.

Comment: Thanks, now it works!
is there a way how to configure it on server side?

Comment: @Dlike: No there is not.

Answer (score -1):

Use the git protocol instead of the ssh and you will not nee the username and port

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol

> ***SSH, aka git@: instead of ssh://git@.com/***
>
> Uses public-key authentication. You have to generate a keypair (or "public key"), then add it to your GitHub account.
>
> Using keys is more secure than passwords, since you can add many to the same account (for example, a key for every computer you need to connect to the server).
>
> The private keys on your computer can be protected with passphrases.

Comment: The question is "how do I do X" and your answer is "don't do X at all but do Y instead".

Comment: Agree. some developer are not aware of the different options. This is also a more generic way since you don't relay on parameters which might be changed later port (user/port etc) This is why i post it and did not place the same answer as you did which will work of course.